# Access a NAS from two separate networks (optionally using an openWRT device)

Tags: nas, bridge, vlan

I've ordered some components to build my own NAS which I want to share with my sister living next door. For that, we wanted to connect these two networks together but leaving them in their respective subnets (both networks have their own DHCP and ISP)

At first, I thought to get a mini-pc with two NIC's but that drove the price too high, so I was hoping I can manage this using a TP-WL841N with Lede / OpenWRT installed. This device is now operating as a simple WAP and switch.
While configuring this device, it seemed to me that it is possible to use VLANs on its LAN-ports.
Can anyone advise me which route I should go to be able to access the NAS from both networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to do this, but a far easier solution, was to attach a usb to ethernet adapter, plugin the second network in that.
Luckily this other network is in another subnet, so there shouldn't be any confusement

Ask me if you'd like more details about my setup...